# Botón de reinicio no funciona

Tags: javascript

Estaba haciendo un juego para practicar JS; necesito que el botón de reinicio inicie de nuevo el ciclo como si diera un refresh a la página. Ya hice funcionar todo, solo necesito este último botón al pie de la caja.

```js
let intentos = 3;

function revisarIntento (){ //Las funciones son reusables, por si necesitas correrlo varias veces
    let miIntento = Number(adivina.value) ; //Se accede al valor previamente añadido al HTML usando el .value
    const numeroAleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    console.log('Numero Aleatorio', numeroAleatorio); //Pal debug

    if (miIntento!== numeroAleatorio) { //Primero comparar el numero que se ingresa con el que se genero con un booleano
        intentos--
        retorno.textContent = "Tu intento fue " + miIntento + ". El numero es incorrecto. Intentalo de nuevo."; // El .textContent se usa para acceder al elemento y poner el texto que quiero.
        numeroIntentos.textContent = "Intentos restantes: " + intentos;
        if (intentos < 1){
            retorno.textContent = "Pasaste el numero de intentos. El juego se terminó";
            intentos = 4;
        }
    } else {
        retorno.textContent = "Acertaste" ;
    }
}
ingresar.addEventListener('click', revisarIntento) // Usando el ID + addEventListener le decimos a JS que evento debe realizar.

function reinicio(){  
    document.getElementById("tAgain").reset();  
}

tAgain.addEventListener('click', reinicio)
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #2980b9, #8e44ad);
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.caja{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 400px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.caja h1{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}

input[type="submit"]{
    width: 30%;
    height: 25px;
    border: .3px solid;
    background: #2691d9;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: auto;
    color: #e9f4fb;
    font-weight: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Adivina adivinador</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="caja">
        <h1>Adivina que numero pienso</h1>
        <p>Estoy pensando en un numero del 1 al 10. ¿Puedes adivinar cual es?</p>

        <div class="datos">
            <label for="adivina">Mi intento</label>
            <input type="text" id="adivina">
            <input type="submit" id="ingresar" value="Revisa mi intento">

            <p id="retorno"></p>
            <p id="numeroIntentos">Intentos restantes: 3 </p>
        </div>
        <div id="jugarOtra">
            <p>¿Quieres jugar de nuevo?</p>
            <input type="submit" id="tAgain" value="Reiniciar">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a poner esto al final de la función `revisarIntento()`?    `document.getElementById("adivina").value = ""`

Comment: No, me refiero a que quiero que el botón haga lo mismo que haría el "Refresh" en el navegador con el boton:
 <input type="submit" id="tAgain" value="Reiniciar">

Comment: ¿un window.location.href a la misma url donde estas?  Agregaselo a la funcion reinicio pues y quita lo del reset() que da error y estropea lo que ocurra despues.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
function reinicio(){  
    location.reload()
}
```

Tal como dice su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Location/reload):

> El metodo location.reload() carga de nuevo la URL actual, como lo hace
> el boton de Refresh de los navegadores.